# Tests with JMS and Spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jms, testng

In my system I am using Spring and JMS (HornetQ).

When running tests on the system some of my tests send JMS events to the messaging queue. JMS opens a thread for each of these messages and runs them. However, I must wait for the JMS thread to end before I can move on to the next test.

Since the main test thread has no idea that another thread is running in the background which is relevant to the test it exits and moves on to the next test before the JMS thread has finished. This makes my life a living hell, seeing as I need to write JMS hooks so I can wait for the JMS thread to finish before I can move on. No matter how I try, I am having trouble catching all of these threads.

What I would really like to do is have the event I am throwing to the messaging queue run in the same thread that runs the tests themselves. This way the message handling must be finished before the test itself will be finished. How can I do this?

--After edit-- 
It has been awhile since i asked this question and still no answer. Is it really possible that no one has implemented such a simple solution for jms in test enviroments?

Comment: Have you checked the properties starting with 'BlockOn...' in the HornetQ manual? http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/index.html#d0e7682

Comment: Thank you. i tried it but it doesn't seem to work. any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make some asynchronous tests, take a look at 

[Awaitility](http://code.google.com/p/awaitility/).

I have used it, and it does the job quite well :)

Comment: I know this one, but this is a workaround. I would like to access JMS synchronously